# cleanup not running in the reducer

Tags: java, hadoop

I've been playing around with Hadoop 2.0 in the Cloudera VM 4.7. I'm trying to print the 5 most occuring words in the `cleanup` method which the [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html) describes how to use. But it doesn't get called at all.

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    private java.util.Map<String, Integer> top5 = new HashMap<String, Integer>(5);

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
        int sum = 0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            sum += values.next().get();
        }
        reporter.getCounter(statistics.UNIQUE_TERMS).increment(1);
        if (sum < 5) {
            reporter.getCounter(statistics.LT5_TERM).increment(1);
        }

        if (this.top5.size() < 5) {
            top5.put(key.toString(), sum);
        } else {
            for (Entry<String, Integer> e : this.top5.entrySet()) {
                if (sum > e.getValue()) {
                    this.top5.remove(e.getKey());
                    this.top5.put(key.toString(), sum);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }

    protected void cleanup(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(this.top5);
    }
}
```

How do I get the method to run like it is supposed to?

**Edit:** This problem also applies to the `setup` method and in the mapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `@Override` annotation to your `cleanup` method.

Also if you are using an old API, you must check if the Mapper interface extends the `Closable` interface - which defines the close method (rather than cleanup which is the method for the new mapreduce API mapper)

```
@Override
public void close() {

}
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get the error `The method cleanup(Reducer.Context) of type WordCount.Reduce must override or implement a supertype method`

Comment: @Joren I've upated the answer.